# Django race condition test with before_after

Tags: python, django, race-condition

I have finished the Django polls tutorial I wanted to continue on it by making a test to check for a voting race condition as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/#s-write-a-simple-form). I found a python package called [before_after](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/before_after/1.0.0) that can be used to make tests involving race conditions. However I don't understand the parameters for the `before` and `after` methods. I've looked over [some examples](http://www.oreills.co.uk/2015/03/01/testing-race-conditions-in-python.html) and thought `Choice.get_votes` is what I needed for my first parameter, however that causes me to get `ImportError: No module named 'Choice'`. Does anyone know what I need to change in my test to get it to work?

Here's the test I made:

tests.py:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Question, Choice
import before_after

def create_question(question_text, days):
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)

class ChoiceTest(TestCase):

    def test_race_condition_avoided(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.creating_race_condition(), 2, "Votes do not equal amount expected.")

    def test_race_condition_occurred(self):
        self.assertNotEqual(self.creating_race_condition(), 1, "Votes do equal amount expected from a race condition.")

    def creating_race_condition(self):
        q = create_question('Did the race condition happen?', 0)
        self.choice = q.choice_set.create(choice_text="Let's find out.", votes=0)
        with before_after.after('Choice.get_votes', self.increment_vote):
            self.increment_vote()
        return c.votes

    def increment_vote(self):
        self.choice.votes += 1
        self.choice.save()

    def get_votes(self):
        return self.choice.votes
```

models.py:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

I am using Python 3.5.1 & Django 1.10.4

Comment: And that link also explains how to avoid that race condition. You need not go on this wild goose chase

Comment: Am I wrong wanting to make a test for it?

Comment: it's very difficult to simulate a race condition in a unit test. And most of the time you don't need third party packages.

Answer (score 0):

`before_after` needs you to use a full path to import the function.

You need to use str like `'vote.models.Choice.get_votes'` to give it full import path.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the [before-after](https://pypi.org/project/before_after/) package is a bit counterintuitive. Here's my solution.

**polls/models.py** - model implement is ignored.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

class Choice(models.Model):
    ...
```

**polls/views.py** - to shorten the code, I remove the error handling by intention here. Hopefully the log would help with better demonstration.

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    print('REQUEST STARTED')
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    print('DB QUERIED')
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    # use the F() expressions to avoid race condition
    selected_choice.votes = F('votes') + 1
    selected_choice.save()
    print('DB UPDATED')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**polls/tests.py**

```
class QuestionVoteViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_vote_increment_race(self):
        """
        When there're multiple votes increments to the same choice
        happening simultaneously,
        the value should be updated accordingly.
        """
        # the helper `create_question` returns a tuple
        # containing the question obj & a list of
        # the passing choices obj
        (past_question, [choice]) = create_question(
            question_text='Past Question.',
            days=-5,
            choices=['choice'],
        )
        # create a request instance here
        # to test the view function without using the test client
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.METHOD = 'POST'
        request.POST['choice'] = choice.id
        # here's the trickiest thing.
        # 1. the first argument should be the full path of the module,
        #    polls/models.py:Choice
        # 2. I fail here creating the second thread
        #    right after the first thread's DB query
        #    `polls.models.Question.choice_set.get` doesn't work
        #    so instead I create the second thread before updating the DB,
        #    and it works.
        with before_after.before(
            'polls.models.Choice.save',
            lambda _: vote(request, past_question.id),
        ):
            vote(request, past_question.id)
        self.assertEqual(Choice.objects.get(pk=choice.id).votes, 2)
```

When the test is run, log would be:

> - REQUEST STARTED
> - DB QUERIED
> - REQUEST STARTED
> - DB QUERIED
> - DB UPDATED
> - DB UPDATED

Related blog link: http://www.c-oreills.com/2015/03/01/testing-race-conditions-in-python.html